# Getting duplication WITH partition by

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, partition

I want to know which customers who ordered in June 2020 also ordered in June 2021. My code returns the correct DISTINCT orders, but discounted sales is incorrect for customers who placed more than one order in either year. For example, a customer who placed one order in 2020 and four orders in 2021 has 2020 discounted sales at 4x the actual amount. The four orders in 2021 have four rows, and the one 2020 order populates against each. I saw this by using ROW_NUMBER () which exposed the underlying problem. I cannot use DISTINCT with discounted sales because customers do place multiple orders for identical dollar amounts. How do I get the exact discounted sales using standard SQL for BQ?

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ly.cuid AS cuid,
COUNT(DISTINCT ly.order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ly.cuid) AS ly_orders,
SUM(ly.discounted_sales) OVER (PARTITION BY ly.cuid) AS ly_demand,
COUNT(DISTINCT ty.order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY ty.cuid) AS ty_orders,
SUM(ty.discounted_sales) OVER (PARTITION BY ly.cuid) AS ty_demand
    
    FROM table ly

        LEFT JOIN table ty
        ON ly.cuid = ty.cuid

        WHERE ly.order_date BETWEEN '2020-06-01' AND '2020-06-30'
        AND ty.order_date BETWEEN '2021-06-01'AND '2021-06-30'
        AND ly.financial_status <> 'credit'
        AND ty.financial_status <> 'credit'
        AND ly.discounted_sales >0
        AND ty.discounted_sales >0
        AND ly.channel = 'b2b'
        AND ty.channel = 'b2b'
        ORDER BY ly.cuid asc
```

[Results]

```
cuid    ly_orders    ly_demand  ty_orders    ty_demand  comments
D       1            22,466.40  4            154,596.24 ly is 4x actual
F       2             2,573.20  1              1,944.40 ty is 2x actual
G       1            32,134.40  4              1,632.00 ly is 4x actual
I       2               757.56  1                730.56 ty is 2x actual
J       2            54,859.00  2             23,822.32 both are 2x actual
```

THIS WORKED:

```
WITH prior_period AS (
SELECT 
DISTINCT cuid AS ly_cuid,
COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid) AS ly_orders,
SUM(discounted_sales) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid) AS ly_demand
    FROM TABLE 
        WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM order_date) = 2020 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date) = 6
        AND financial_status <> 'credit'
        AND discounted_sales >0
        AND channel = 'b2b'
        GROUP BY cuid, order_id, discounted_sales
        ORDER BY cuid asc),

    this_period AS (
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT cuid AS ty_cuid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid) AS ty_orders,
    SUM(discounted_sales) OVER (PARTITION BY cuid) AS ty_demand
    FROM TABLE 
        WHERE EXTRACT (YEAR FROM order_date) = 2021 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date) = 6
        AND financial_status <> 'credit'
        AND discounted_sales >0
        AND channel = 'b2b'
        GROUP BY cuid, order_id, discounted_sales
        ORDER BY cuid asc)

        SELECT *
        FROM prior_period ly
        JOIN this_period ty ON ly.ly_cuid = ty.ty_cuid
        ORDER BY ly.ly_cuid
```

Comment: It would help to see the data and expected result.  Basically, you need to aggregate for each side of the JOIN first, then join that aggregated data.  Otherwise, your join will cause your `SUM`s / `COUNT`s to be impacted by the rows in the other table.

Comment: Thank you, Jon. I will try to do that. I just learned SQL a few weeks ago.

I'm not allowed to imbed photos yet, and when I paste the results, it's a mess as you can now see.

Comment: That's correct.  Aggregate before the join.  But you're missing other details, like the fact that you didn't need `DISTINCT` if you use `GROUP BY`.  Window functions are fine when you don't want to aggregate the groups/partitions into one row each.  If you notice my solution, I avoid that and just use `GROUP BY`.  There's some simplification you get with my approach.

Comment: If you can provide a little test data, that might help.  Your use of `GROUP BY` might be a mistake or at least partially unnecessary, when combined with the window function use.

Answer (score 0):

Updated with your schema and approximate data:

Try this...

```
WITH periods AS (
      SELECT cuid     AS cuid
           , COUNT(*) AS orders
           , SUM(discounted_sales) AS demand
           , EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) AS yr
        FROM demand2
       WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date) IN (2020, 2021) AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM order_date) = 6
         AND financial_status <> 'credit'
         AND discounted_sales > 0
         AND channel = 'b2b'
       GROUP BY cuid, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM order_date)
     )
SELECT ly.cuid
     , ly.orders AS ly_orders
     , ly.demand AS ly_demand
     , ty.orders AS ty_orders
     , ty.demand AS ty_demand
  FROM periods AS ly
  JOIN periods AS ty
    ON ly.cuid = ty.cuid
   AND ly.yr = 2020
   AND ty.yr = 2021
 ORDER BY ly.cuid
;
```

The result:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| cuid | ly_orders | ly_demand | ty_orders | ty_demand |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| D    |         1 |   5616.60 |         4 | 154596.24 |
| F    |         2 |   2573.20 |         1 |    972.20 |
| G    |         1 |   8033.60 |         4 |   1632.56 |
| I    |         2 |    757.56 |         1 |    365.28 |
| J    |         2 |  27429.50 |         2 |  11911.16 |
+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Here's a similar example with data, SQL and results to show both the incorrect result and the correct result.

The data:

```
SELECT * FROM demand ORDER BY account_id, period;

+----+------------+--------+--------+
| id | account_id | period | demand |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
|  1 |          1 | 202005 |    100 |
|  2 |          1 | 202005 |    120 |
|  3 |          1 | 202105 |    105 |
|  4 |          1 | 202105 |    125 |
|  5 |          1 | 202105 |     30 |
|  6 |          2 | 202005 |    200 |
|  7 |          2 | 202105 |    240 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+
```

The incorrect SQL, without `SUM`s to just show the join behavior:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.account_id, t1.period, t1.demand AS demand1
     , t2.id, t2.period, t2.demand AS demand2
  FROM      demand AS t1
  LEFT JOIN demand AS t2
    ON t1.account_id = t2.account_id
   AND t2.period = 202105
 WHERE t1.period = 202005
 ORDER BY t1.account_id, t1.period, demand1, demand2
;

+----+------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------+
| id | account_id | period | demand1 | id   | period | demand2 |
+----+------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------+
|  1 |          1 | 202005 |     100 |    5 | 202105 |      30 |
|  1 |          1 | 202005 |     100 |    3 | 202105 |     105 |
|  1 |          1 | 202005 |     100 |    4 | 202105 |     125 |
|  2 |          1 | 202005 |     120 |    5 | 202105 |      30 |
|  2 |          1 | 202005 |     120 |    3 | 202105 |     105 |
|  2 |          1 | 202005 |     120 |    4 | 202105 |     125 |
|  6 |          2 | 202005 |     200 |    7 | 202105 |     240 |
+----+------------+--------+---------+------+--------+---------+
```

Notice account 2 doesn't have a problem because only one demand was found last year and this year.

But account 1 found 2 demand rows for last year and 3 demand rows for this year, leading to (2 x 3) = 6 rows in the joined result.  This is the source of the problem.

To correct this, we aggregate before the `JOIN`, so that we have at most one (1) row per account / period to be joined.

One form of the correct solution, with `SUM`s derived in the `CTE` term:

```
WITH demands AS (
         SELECT account_id, period
              , SUM(demand) AS demand
              , COUNT(*)    AS orders
           FROM demand
          GROUP BY account_id, period
     )
SELECT ly.account_id, ly.period
     , ly.orders AS ly_orders
     , ly.demand AS ly_demand
     , ty.orders AS ty_orders
     , ty.demand AS ty_demand
  FROM      demands AS ly
  LEFT JOIN demands AS ty
    ON ly.account_id = ty.account_id
   AND ty.period = 202105
 WHERE ly.period = 202005
 ORDER BY ly.account_id, ly.period, ly_demand, ty_demand
;
```

The result:

```
+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| account_id | period | ly_orders | ly_demand | ty_orders | ty_demand |
+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|          1 | 202005 |         2 |       220 |         3 |       260 |
|          2 | 202005 |         1 |       200 |         1 |       240 |
+------------+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Since we performed aggregation in the `CTE` term (`demands`), the join found at most one row for each period for each account.